# Adding missing part in pattern

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, hough-transform

I have a video stream where I'm recording simple pattern with circles. I need to detect them. I'm using HoughCircles. Here's a sample frame:

[image]

But sometimes I didn't detect every circle in pattern.

[image]

My goal is to save pattern when detect all circles , and next if i didn't detect all try to approximate possible position and draw rectangle there. Problem is that sometimes I miss one circle, sometimes I miss two. My code for detection:

```
gauss = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(21,21),0);
blurred = cv2.medianBlur(gauss, 21)  
minDist = 70
param1 = 20#30 #smaller value-> more false circles
param2 = 30#50 #smaller value-> more false circles
minRadius = 10
maxRadius = 50
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blurred, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist, param1=param1, param2=param2, minRadius=minRadius, maxRadius=maxRadius)
```

I played a little bit with different parameters (for blurring and Hough) and I guess there is no more room to improve.

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10057/gaussian-blur-standard-deviation-radius-and-kernel-size

Comment: In addition to the marked-up images you have provided, can you supply the unmarked-up images *as original images* rather than as screen-grabs. Thank you.

Comment: As I said is screenshot from thermal camera so view changes dynamically. For my purpose it better to somehow calculate the approximated position of missing circles. https://ibb.co/rtn3bwW